# Issues with pygame and libmpg123-0.dll

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("water.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while True:

    print("Press 'p' to pause, 'r' to resume")
    print("Press 'e' to exit the program")
    query = input("  ")

    if query == 'p':
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        
    elif query == 'r':
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        
    elif query == 'e':
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        break
```

I wrote this but error showing this

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python Programming\play_sound.py", line 7, in 
pygame.mixer.music.load("water.mp3")
pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123-0.dll: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with your code. The problem is related to your system. You have not provided enough information. What is your Python and Pygame version, what is your IDE, how did you install pygame?

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 options you can try all of them and can see which ones work for you

1.Restart your IDE if that doesn't work try restarting your PC.

2.uninstalled and reinstalled the "pygame" library from this site. [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame). which worked well.

3.
Step 1: Go to browser and search download libmpg123.dll.

Step 2: download libmpg123.dll and Extract it.

Step 3: After Extract (cut or copy) the two docs and paste in "C:\Windows\System32".

Step 4: Installation is successfully done.

4. Or you can convert your mp3 file to a WAV file and then use it.

Answer (score -1):

Download libmpg123-0.dll from google or search for it in your AppData.
Now copy the file into your C:/Windows/System32 folder.

It should work!!